# What design pattern do I need to replace every table row except the first one, along with an AJAX insertion mode?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table

```
<table class="table-striped col-lg-12" id="results">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Generate link
        </th>
        <th>
            Organization
        </th>
        <th>
            Category
        </th>
        <th>
            File
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

that must have at least that one row (the row that supplies the titles of the other rows), plus whatever rows are returned from the result of my search algorithm. My problem is that if I use

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "SurfaceAssets", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
```

for the form, then rows are added to rows of my previous search results. On the other hand, if I use `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace` then I lose the title row. The best solution I can think of is having extra JavaScript that removes rows 2, 3, ..., before running the AJAX method with `InsertAfter`, but that's hackish because I then have to change the submit input element to something like

```
<input type="submit" value="Search!" action="clearTableAndSubmit()"/>
```

and make a function

```
function clearTableAndSubmit()
{
    $('#results > tr:nth-of-type(n+2)').each($(this).remove());
    $('form').submit();
}
```

So what is the best solution here?

(Also, how do I set an id for the form using AjaxOptions? I don't see any way of doing it according to this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try using [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) / `<tbody>` elements to structure your table?

The `UpdateTargetId = "results"` indicates that you're *updating* the contents of the table, which implies your request is responding with an HTML snippet of `<tr>`s - there should be no problem inserting these into a `<tbody>` element instead of a `<table>`.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Generate link</th>
      ...
    </tr> 
  </thead>

  <tbody id="results"></tbody>

</table>
```

Or you could just return the headers as part of your ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following code snippet to assign id to ajax.beginform 
`@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action","Controller",null,new AjaxOptions {InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,UpdateTargetId = "div",HttpMethod = "Post"}, new {@id = "frmID" })){  }`